# c programming quiz average array within for loop

Tags: c, arrays

I'm stuck on a problem. I'm trying to find the average for the QUIZZES in this program assignment. Here's my code. The code in Bold is where my problem is.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define STUDENTS 4
 #define QUIZZES 5

 main () {

int quizScores [STUDENTS] [QUIZZES] = {
    { 90, 90, 90, 90, 90 },
    { 90, 80, 70, 60, 50 },
    { 90, 89, 88, 87, 86 },
    { 90, 85, 80, 75, 70 }
 };
 int studentTotal = 0, quizTotal, row, col;
 double studentAverage, quizAverage;

 for ( row = 0; row < STUDENTS; row++) {
     studentTotal = 0;
     for ( col = 0; col < QUIZZES; col++) {
         studentTotal += quizScores[row][col];
     }
     studentAverage = (double) studentTotal / QUIZZES;
     printf("Student %i has average %.2lf\n", row, studentAverage);
 }

 **for ( col = 0; col < QUIZZES; col++) {
     quizTotal = 0;
     for ( row = 0; row < STUDENTS; row++) {
         quizTotal += quizScores[col][row];  
     }
     quizAverage = (double) quizTotal / STUDENTS;
     printf("Quiz %i has an average %.2lf\n",col, quizAverage);
     // output the average for this quiz
 }**

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Note that an effective way of debugging a problem such as this is to print the values you are processing as you are processing them.  You can also use the debugger to step through the code to see what's going on.  For example, if you printed `printf("quiz[%d][%d] = %f\n", col, row, quizScores[col][row]);` in the second loop, you'd spot weird numbers as you go, which would make you look really hard at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have the indices mixed up in `quizTotal += quizScores[col][row];`. It should be `quizTotal += quizScores[row][col];`.

Comment: >< Simple mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. I was wondering why my output for "Quiz 4 has an average of" kept giving me a negative weird number i.e  -3215461312513.15  Again. Thank you.